# C# DropDown smart logic

Tags: c#, winforms, arraylist, dropdownlistfor

I've got a ComboBox in ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList style.

[image]

This gets dynamically created based on the number of a passed paremeter. The letters is an ArrayList of letters which are added to the dropdown

```
for (int a = i; a < drivesLetters.Count; a++) //drivesLetters {"A", "K", "M", so on so forth} 
{
    combobox.Items.Add(drivesLetters[a]); //add driveletters at element i to the combobox
}
```

I've been trying to create a method so that when I click on a dropdown list, the letters which are already selected on other dropdown lists should not show up from the selections. Like on the image above, If I click on M, then M should not show up in the dropdowns which have currently A and K selected. If I select V, then V should be selected, not show on the list, M should be added.

My goal is for each of the ComboBox to have a unique Value. It is to prevent users from choosing the same letter "A" to two ComboBox.

I'm not sure how to actually do this. I wonder if I should have two ArrayLists (one holds the letters used in the dropdown, and another one to hold all the unused letters).

I am looking at an implementation like [this (in javascript)](http://jsbin.com/siqolemove/edit?html,js,output) but obviously in C#.

Please kindly point me to a good starting point. I've tried so many methods, but no success..

Thanks!

Comment: The JS example you gave shows warnings and doesn't do what you seem to be saying it does. When a user selects a letter in one ComboBox, do you want to remove that letter from the available letters in _all_ of the ComboBoxes, including the one the user just selected from? Or exclude it from just the remaining two ComboBoxes, not the one the user selected from?

Comment: Hi Peter, Thank you so much for your input. You are right! I did not notice it. I apologize, I'll edit my description. With regards to your question, I would like to remove the letter from the available letters in _all_ of the ComboBoxes. Including the one the user just selected from. Thank you :)

Comment: Hi Peter Duniho, upon rethinking what I was aiming to achieve, I thought _excluding a letter from just the remaining two ComboBoxes, not the one the user selected from_ is also fine. I'm redesigning my algorithm on paper now. But anyones' help is still greatly appreciated! thanks :)

Comment: Okay...I strongly recommend you stick with that alternative instead of removing it from all three. To remove it from all three would confuse and annoy users.

Comment: Hi Peter, thank you for your input. I totally agree with you regarding your statement. But I think I have not explained myself well. My aim is to prevent two ComboBoxes from having the same letter "A". I hope this clears it

Comment: Yes, I think so and as I mentioned before I think that alternative would work fine. I posted a short code example that I hope is helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like this should accomplish your goal:

```
private void comboBox_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox[] comboBoxes = { comboBox1, comboBox2, comboBox3 };
    ComboBox senderBox = (ComboBox)sender;

    char senderSelection = (char)senderBox.SelectedItem;

    foreach (ComboBox comboBox in comboBoxes)
    {
        if (comboBox != senderBox)
        {
        char comboBoxSelection = (char)comboBox.SelectedItem;

        comboBox.Items.Clear();
        comboBox.Items.AddRange(_driveLetters.Where(
            letter => letter != senderSelection).Cast<object>().ToArray());
        comboBox.SelectedItem = comboBoxSelection;
        }
    }
}
```

...where the code assumes your ComboBoxes are named comboBox1, comboBox2, and comboBox3 and `_driveLetters` is an instance member `IEnumerable<char>` (e.g. List, char[], etc.) that holds the valid drive letters to display. This one event handler would be assigned to the SelectedItemChanged event on all three ComboBoxes.

Obviously you'd adjust the variable names and types to suit your specific purposes. Also, I apologize in advance for any typos and compiler errors. I just typed that here, without compiling or testing. I assume it's close enough to something usable to get you going. :)

Comment: Hi Peter, thank you for your answer. I am getting close to figuring it out. However, can you please expand on `char senderSelection = (char)senderBox.SelectedItem` as it is not being used in the method, and I dont know the use of it. Thank you :)

Comment: Ah, sorry...good catch! I typed the wrong variable name in the Where() method. I've edited the post to fix that.